# Pig count clarification

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have pig count clarification

```
transactions = LOAD '/user/valivetv/transactions.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (transaction_id:long,transaction_date:datetime, cust_id:long, age:chararray, area:chararray, prod_subclass:int, prod_id:long, amt:int, asset:int, sales_price:int, phone_no:chararray, country_code:chararray);
data_grpd = GROUP transactions ALL;
string_stats = FOREACH data_grpd GENERATE  group,COUNT_STAR(transactions.country_code),COUNT(transactions.country_code);
string_stats1 = FOREACH data_grpd GENERATE  group,COUNT_STAR(transactions),COUNT(transactions);
```

I notice string_stats and string_stat1 both are giving same output.

what is differnece between COUNT(transactions.country_code) and COUNT(transactions)?

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(transactions.country_code)` will count a bag of just `country_code` tuples, whereas `COUNT(transactions)` will count a bag of tuples will all of the original fields from the transactions relation that you loaded in.

If you are seeing the same output, without seeing your original data, maybe every record has data for the `country_code` field? In which case, COUNT is essentially returning the number of records in your original data.